# I want set style property from javascript variable

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var prop = 'width';
document.getElementById('divName').style.prop = '100px';
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with bracket notation

```
var prop = 'width';
document.getElementById('divName').style[prop] = '100px';
```

Answer (score 0):

In js object properties can be accessed by two ways.

One way is using . operator if you know property name. e.g. style.width = '100px'

Second way is using square brackets [] if property name is stored in variable. e.g. prop = 'width'; style[prop] = '100px'